# spark non maven dependency in an intellij project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am working on a Spark project using `Intellij` as an ide. I build an artifact that runs locally well. When I run

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn myjar.jar
```

I get this message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

The project uses both `maven` and some dependencies directly loaded inside `intellij`. How can I deal with that ? Should I only use `maven` for dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and you should only use Maven dependencies. I guess you created your jar with maven install/build. Try creating your jar from the IDE. In `eclipse` it is `file -> export as jar file` and see if the new jar works. I had the same problem and for me creating the jar from the IDE solved it. And I think it is due to the `intelij` dependencies.
Good luck!